# Adjust shipping cost based on product Variation?

Tags: expresso-store

We're using Store to sell magazines that have three variations: Print, Digital and Print + Digital. We're currently using Flat Rate shipping with a base rate and a per-item cost. However, if the visitor selects only the Digital version of an individual magazine, can we override the shipping costs for that particular product, while keeping Flat Rate shipping costs in place for any other products in the cart?

Answer (score 2):

At the moment you would need to write an extension or a custom shipping extension to have per variation specific shipping rates. I would recommend sending an email to support@exp-resso.com with the feature request so they can add it to the [Feature Request](https://exp-resso.com/support/feature-requests) list to see about getting it added to a future release.

You can find the extension hooks documentation [here](https://exp-resso.com/docs/extension_hooks.html).

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to add different shipping prices to product variations using Store's built in features. You have two options:

- Write an extension using the [extension hooks](https://exp-resso.com/docs/extension_hooks.html) to change the shipping price based on what the customer has selected.
- Create separate products for digital/print versions of your magazines, and use categories to separate them. That way you can add additional handling charges to the print versions.